# Tweaking the variables in integration

Tags: integration

I do not understand why these two equations are equal. If *t* is replaced by *x + t*, shouldn't *x-t* be replaced by *-t* (=x-(x+t)) rather than by t?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but so is the solution. Note that the sum goes from $-N$ to $N$, so changing the order of summation yields
$$\sum \limits_{j = -N}^N e^{-ijt} = \sum \limits_{j = -N}^N e^{ijt}.$$

This is under the assumption that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, as otherwise the substitution is incorrect in the first place.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks!